# php display only the last result of a if loop

Tags: php, wordpress, for-loop, postdata

I'm using a loop on my website to display the previous post permalinks of a current post.

```
<?php
global $post;
$current_post = $post;
for($i = 1; $i <= 30; $i++):
$post = get_previous_post();
setup_postdata($post); ?>

<?php if($post): ?>

<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="next_link">Next Posts</a>

<?php endif; ?>
<?php endfor;
wp_reset_postdata();
$post = $current_post; 
?>
```

using this loop I get 30 times the "next posts" link.
what I want to do, is to only get the last result of this loop.

for the moment, I'm using css and jquery to only display the last link, using this css :

```
a.next_link {display:none}
a.next_link:last-child {display: block}
```

but as you can imagine it's not a nice solution.

I would like to run the loop and only get the last $post.

is there a way adding some php to my loop to only get the last $post of this loop ?

thanks for your help,

Comment: Output after the `endfor` rather then inside. Why run the `for` though if you dont care about the other 29?

Comment: Throw away a loop and just `$post = get_previous_post();`?

Comment: @u_mulder, I display 29 posts on my current post, before this loop, so I need to get the 30 previous posts, and then display only the last of those 30 posts, to go to my next post. It's a trick to add an offset to get_previous_post() function.

Comment: @u_mulder screw it ?  thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is skip the previous 29 entries, since WP doesn't provide you a way to do that out of the box. Use [`continue`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php) to manipulate your loop.

```
<?php
global $post;
$current_post = $post;
for($i = 1; $i <= 30; $i++):
$post = get_previous_post();
if ($i != 30):
  continue;
endif;
setup_postdata($post); ?>

<?php if($post): ?>

<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="next_link">Next Posts</a>

<?php endif; ?>
<?php endfor;
wp_reset_postdata();
$post = $current_post; 
?>
```

Comment: works like a charm, thanks a lot ! I did not know about the continue function... gonna use it a lot !